# Why book re-ordering is not being saved?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.38. When I re-order book pages and then hit the `Save` button, the ordering stays the same. If I open individual nodes and change weight of each one then it works, but that will take a lot of time.

Any idea why the re-ordering is not being saved?

Comment: How many "book pages" does your book have?

Comment: the pages are about 250

Comment: Is your JS working properly, updating hidden fields?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old bug when you have too many pages, I've been struggling and finally still doing it through MySQL :

```
it's 'menu_links' table and Weight value in DB , and flush cache well

it's from my old question How to reorder Book module menu through Database?
```

Hello, who deleted My Answer?! - This IS ANSWER not Bug report, indeed! You can use my answer about MYSQL data tables! Why joke and delete?!

Answer (score 1):

The page has a lot of hidden input fields for each book you have. You are hitting the max input var limit set in PHP.  Increasing the php configuration setting for max_input_vars and it should solve your problem.  http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars